# What is the significance of $\hbar$ appearing in classical equation of motion?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants, klein-gordon-equation, classical-field-theory

Books on QFT treats, any quantum field as quantized classical fields. For example, the Klein-Gordon field is first treated as a classical field $\phi(x)$ obeying classical Euler-Lagrange equation $$\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial\phi}-\partial_\mu\Big(\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu\phi)}\Big)=0\Rightarrow(\Box+m^2)\phi(x)=0.\tag{1}$$ However, if we restore the units $\hbar$ and $c$, it becomes $$(\Box+\frac{m^2c^2}{\hbar^2})\phi(x)=0.$$

1. How can the classical equation of motion (1) depend upon $\hbar$?
2. For electromagnetic field, this problem is not there. The Maxwell's equations do not contain $\hbar$. Is there a deep reason (apart from any accident) why Maxwell's equation do not contain $\hbar$ but the classical KG equation, classical Dirac equation does?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/670179/2451

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In classical mechanics there is no reason to identify $m$ with a mass. It is just an inverse of a length, in which case there are no factors of $\hbar$ nor $c$ in the KG equation.

Comment: Dear @AFT If you took the Fourier mode expansion of the field $\phi(x)$, each classical mode satisfies relativistic dispersion relation. So I doubt your answer.

Comment: @SRS so what? you may have a Fourier variable satisfy $k^2=m^2$ and still there is no reason to identify $m$ with a mass. In classical mechanics $k$ is not the momentum of anything. There are no particles in CM.

Comment: $m$ in OP's (1) looks like the inverse of a length.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform My idea was that the KG equation was historically obtained in RQM (which contains $\hbar$ and $c$). In field theory, this KG equation is thought of  as the Euler-Lagrange equation derived from a Lagrangian. And therefore, this Lagrangian must also have factors of $\hbar$ and $c$. Isn't it? If the classical Lagrangian doesn't have factors of $\hbar$ and $c$, how does it suddenly appear after quantizing the theory?

Comment: @SRS it does not "suddenly appear after quantizing the theory", because the Q theory is conceptually independent of the C theory. In practice, it is useful to start with a C theory and quantise it, but as a matter of principle, the C theory is irrelevant to the Q one. There is no transition in the direction $\mathrm{CM}\to\mathrm{QM}$ (though there is a transition in the opposite direction: the classical limit). In other words, the factors of $\hbar,c$ do not suddenly appear, because the Q theory *is* the starting point. A Q theory is not the result of a process that begins at a certain C thry

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Although I had accepted the answer but now I've again confused myself. If we start only with $m$ (and no $\hbar$ or $c$) in the Lagrangian, how/when does $c$ enter the picture? I understand that $\hbar$ enter upon imposing the canonical commutation relations. I think $c$ is there even in the classical Lagrangian because the classical theory is relativistic ($\partial_0$ contains $c$ ).

Comment: @SRS enter the picture where? in classical KG or in quantum KG? in the classical case, $m$ is an inverse length, but you may very well define $\nu:=cm$, which is an inverse time. Whether the equation is expressed in terms of $m$ or $\nu$ is a matter of conventions.

Comment: The classical KG Lagrangian already contains $c$. Right? Therefore, the appropriate Fourier relation $k^2=m^2$ should be properly written as $\omega^2-\textbf{k}^2c^2=m^2c^2$ assuming $m$ to be an inverse length parameter. This would look like a dispersion relation if $\omega\to E, \textbf{k}\to \textbf{p}$ and $m\to mc$.

Comment: @SRS $\uparrow$ Yes.