# Is the mass of elementary particles proportional to the Planck constant?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, mass, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants

I’m reading Manton&Sutcliffe’s “Topological Solitons”. In that book on p. 2, they argue as follows:

> In a Lorentz invariant theory, and in units where the speed of light is unity, the energy of a soliton is identified as its rest mass. In contrast, the elementary particles have a mass proportional to Planck’s constant $\hbar$ (this is sometimes not recognized, because of the choice of units).

This sentence is very confusing for me. Is this sentence simply pointing out that the mass multiplied by $\frac{c}{\hbar}$ in Klein-Gordon equation, described in the Planck units, equals that of the SI units? In other words, does this sentence relate to that the Klein-Gordon equation described in the SI units is $(\Box+(\frac{mc}{\hbar})^2)\phi=0 $, as is $(\Box+m^2)\phi=0$ in the Planck units?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, OP is right. The mass term in the [Klein-Gordon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein%E2%80%93Gordon_equation) or the [Dirac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation) action is $\frac{mc}{\hbar}$ so that it has dimension of inverse length (in order to match the dimension of the spacetime derivative $\partial_{\mu}$ in the kinetic term). But since the classical action does *not* depend$^1$ on $\hbar$, this in turn means that the mass parameter$^2$ $m$ is really proportional to $\hbar$.

--

$^1$ The reduced Planck constant $\hbar$ is here treated as a free parameter rather than the actual physical value $\approx 1.05\times 10^{−34} {\rm Js}$.

$^2$ The physical mass $m_{\rm ph}$ is given by a pole
$$(k^0)^2-{\bf k}^2~=~\left(\frac{m_{\rm ph}c}{\hbar}\right)^2 ~=~\left(\frac{mc}{\hbar}\right)^2-\Pi$$ in the connected 2-pt function/propagator. Here $\Pi$ is a [self-energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-energy) term.